# SignalR must call .done or .fail before logic

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I'm trying to create a simple hello world with SignalR. I have a hub,

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void TestConnection(string message)
    {
        Clients.Caller.testConnection(message);
    }
}
```

and a JS file (using Angular),

```
var hub = $.connection.myHub;
hub.client.testMessage = function (message) {
    console.log("Test: " + message);
};
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () { 
    alert('signalR started');  
}).fail(function (reason) {
    console.log("SignalR connection failed: " + reason);
});
hub.server.testConnection("hello signalR").done(function () { });
```

When I load the page, I just want the console to say "hello signalR". I get a the error message: SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized. Use .start().done() or .start().fail() to run logic after the connection has started.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add the `start().fail()` to see if the initialization was failing for some reason?

Comment: @RonBeyer I added it, but it's giving the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () { 
    alert('signalR started');  
    hub.server.testConnection("hello signalR").done(function () { });
});
```

And on the server :

```
Clients.All.testConnection(message);
```

Functions from hub.server must be called after the connection has been started. In your example the javascript was being run but the hub connection hasn't finished starting so you put it in the callback to the .done()

Comment: Thanks man. The All part wasn't necessary, but the JS fixed the issue. I had already tried this once, but I hadn't added the .fail statement, so maybe that was related. Not sure.

Comment: Fail statement is not necessary.All part just specifies to transmit to all who are connected.

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve the issue but you should be calling testMessage from the C# method, not testConnection.